# Scala type classes

Tags: scala

I have a custom type defined as follows:

```
type MyType = (String, String)
```

When I use this type, I always have to go through the tuple numbering which I hate. I can of course do the following and unpack what is inside as below:

```
val (str1, str2) = myType
```

Can I create a companion object for this type and have two methods that gives me the first and the second element in the tuple? I would like to rather do the following:

myType.str1 would give me the first element and myType.str2 would give me the second element.

Comment: Why don't you use a case class ?

Comment: Type aliases don't provide proper static type safety; go with a case class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
scala> type MyType = (String, String)
defined type alias MyType

scala> implicit class MyPair(val t: MyType) extends AnyVal {
     |   def str1 = t._1
     |   def str2 = t._2
     | }
defined class MyPair

scala> val mt: MyType = ("Hello", "World")
mt: MyType = (Hello,World)

scala> mt.str1
res0: String = Hello

scala> mt.str2
res1: String = World
```

Comment: overkill; case class would be preferred here.

Comment: I agree with Erik. This is overengineered, which is a symptom of bad design. A case class would serve the purpose much more idiomatically.

Comment: Also, a Tuple2 *is* a case class; one with annoying accessors. So there really is no benefit in trying to use a tuple here.

Answer (score 13):

> Can I create a companion object for this type and have two methods that gives me the first and the second element in the tuple?

Sure, that's what a case class does.

How about just

```
case class MyType(str1: String, str2: String)
```

without resorting to clumsy type aliases?